# After defining categorical variables as factors, one level is not found in the test set

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, glm, feature-selection

My [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/875w9i23eb5ulpf/rodeo.csv?dl=0) should be divided into train, validation, and test as follows:

```
mydata <- read.csv("rodeo.csv")
set.seed(200)  
n=nrow(mydata)
id.train=sample(1:n,300,replace=FALSE)
id.valid=sample(setdiff(1:n,id.train),100,replace=FALSE)
id.test=setdiff(setdiff(1:n,id.train),id.valid)

mydata.train=mydata[id.train,]
mydata.valid=mydata[id.valid,]
mydata.test=mydata[id.test,]
```

Since revenu, emploi, and rodeo are categorical variables, I defined them as factors:

```
mydata.train$emploi=as.factor(mydata.train$emploi)
mydata.train$revenu=as.factor(mydata.train$revenu)
mydata.train$rodeo=as.factor(mydata.train$rodeo)
```

I should do variable selection in a way that maximizes the AUC, so I did as follows:

```
# Transformation of the variable of interest into a factor, with names for the levels
levels <- unique(mydata.train$achat) 
mydata.train$new_achat=factor(mydata.train$achat, labels=make.names(levels))

data_ctrl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                         classProbs = TRUE)

# Shortcut to include all variables + interactions
model = train(new_achat~emploi + revenu + sexe + univ + age + rodeo
           , data=mydata.train, method="glmStepAIC",metric = "ROC"
           , trControl=data_ctrl,trace=FALSE)
model$finalModel
```

However, when I test the model:

```
mydata.test$emploi=as.factor(mydata.test$emploi)
mydata.test$revenu=as.factor(mydata.test$revenu)
mydata.test$rodeo=as.factor(mydata.test$rodeo)

prob.predict = predict.glm (model$finalModel, mydata.test, type="response")
```

This error will appear:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'revenu3' not found
```

Comment: Without seeing a sample of the your, everything is is just a guess.  It looks like your test set did not include all of the possible factors.  In your dataset how may "revenu3" exist?

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks. I provided the link to my dataset (in the first sentence).